# javascript evaluate simple user submitted math node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, eval

I need to evaluate some simple user submitted math. Multiplication of 2 numbers for example.

This opens me up to injection attacks.

My plan is to whitelist a bunch of values `[^|(|)|\d+|\*|\/|\+|-]` and replace everything else with regex before evaluation.

Any problems with this?

Example strings:

```
324*32
(5+4-17) / 3
```

Comment: Please, add samples of strings to check. As I assume, strings like '54*4' or '5 - 7' must pass the regular expression test?

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but your character class is wrong — you don't need the pipes, `^` at the beginning negates it, and you can't use repetition operators in a character class.  Use `[()^\d*/+-]` instead.

Comment: If you add `[`, `]` and `!` to that set, we can start to do some damage!  `([][1]+[])[2]+(![]+[])[4]+([][1]+[])[1]+([][1]+[])[5]+(![]+[])[4]+([][1]+[])[2]` === `'denied'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of any particularly nasty way to mess up your server too much using just numbers and a handful of operators, however, there are some things you need to look out for:

Given that the `[^...]` is a character class, you do not need to separate every value with `|`. This is probably what you really want: `[^^()\d*\/+-]`. This will match everything you do *not* want to allow.

Additionally, it is important to remember that, in JavaScript, `^` does not represent powers but rather "exclusive or". This means, for example, that `2 ^ 3 == 1`. So you probably do not want to whitelist `^`: `[^()\d*\/+-]`.

You might encounter invalid syntax like `(1 * (2 + 3)`, so you should watch out for that as well. You can probably just have a try catch block and meaningfully deal with things like that (report the problem back to the user or something).